# React app does not work in IE11

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, create-react-app, babel-polyfill

When I load my ES6 react app (created using create-react-app) in production (irlmap.com) in IE11 (other browsers work fine), I get the following error: `Minified React error #185`. I took a screenshot of the console logs, which you can see below. The problems seems to be that `Symbol()` is `undefined`. Digging around google, this seems to be a problem with my polyfill? Note that at the entry to my app (index.js), I have the following:

```
import "babel-polyfill"
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

Console error in IE11:

[image]

Comment: try running the app with the dev server `npm start` and checking IE? you won't be getting a minified error that way and you can see what the actual problem is

Comment: Since it's a production build, its' errors are difficult to track. Try running a development build in said browser and you'll get more helpful errors.
This may be because of any 3rd party package which wasn't built n shipped for IE11, problem may not necessarily be in your code.

Comment: Thanks! I ran in dev mode and found the issue was related to using setState within componentWillUpdate. Still unclear why the error only happened in ie11, but, in any case, the problem is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Include following plugin in your webpack config file.

new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Promise: 'es6-promise-promise', // works as expected
    })

Above code resolved the issues for me.